# List non un1que Strings from textfile

Tags: linux, shell

Can somebody help me finding an command?
This is a part of my list:

E, AABDA, Jasmine Lawley , 94919

O, HJAAA, Archie Gollah, 79867

I, HAUJS, Heidi Clough, 78495

J, HDUSN, Archie Gollah, 78529

H, HUISD, Reece Bristow, 72893

G, HUDWI, Zoe Reinard, 75832

F, DUECX, Zoe Reinard, 72855

The command should List the names of those with more th4n one 3ntry, together with the number of app3arances, in d3sc3nding order

like:

2 Zoe Reinard

2 Archie Gollah

Thank you very mutch!

Comment: this qu3stion is too l33t for m3.

Comment: I wont do *your* cl4ss 4ssignm3nt. .

Comment: If you edit your question to get rid of the asinine leetspeak, I will post an outline of an answer. Why only an outline? [This is why](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166).

Comment: Never mind, outline posted as comment below. Do please read the letter linked above, if you actually want to learn how to program, instead of just getting your degree with minimal effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be written in English (or any intelligble language).

Answer (score 2):

j00 w4nt `4wk` w1th 4ss0c14t1v3 4rr4yz:

```
< text awk -F, '{ a[$3]++; }; END{ for (i in a) { n=a[i]; if(n > 1) print n, i; } } '
```

W0rkz 4z 3xp3ct3d w1th y0 3x4mpL3.

Comment: a sed will do it. But I am not fond of kids dumping here the homework without any manners, and also polluting the quality of the board. elance has lot of 3rd world people that will work for a pittance, and at least they will contribute for some poor soul to eat.

Comment: Why not do it the standard Unix way? `cut | sort | uniq -cd | sort -rn`.

Comment: yep, it was my first idea. You missed a parameter in sort, and still the ","... the kid wont have his homework handed in a plate if you do not correct it. ;->

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Yes, and we certainly wouldn't want *that* to happen. Why, he might actually *learn how to program*, and then we'd have more competition in the job market.

Comment: @TomZych I don't know awk very well, and this seemed like a nice opportunity to try it out some more. But yeah--your solution is better. Or well, it depends. Both solutions are pretty readable and conceptually clear, IMO. tmtowtdi

Comment: He wont learn if we are doing it for him. I have spent hours helping people with genuine doubts, and not just "here you have my home work, do it for me"

Comment: tone it down, guys. point out what you dont like, sure, but *disdain* isnt really helpful.

Comment: sorry I worked on that few hors but cant find a solution I thought you could help me

Comment: Whiile inclusing the l33tsp34k in your answer is undoubtedly amusing, it really doesn't belong here; please edit it out so as to not encourage any more of the idiots...